# Flash AS3 RegExp

Tags: regex, string, actionscript-3, flash

I don't know if I can use the RegExp Object to get a result like I would like as here bellow:
I would like to test an answer that match a part of the correctAnswer variable (case insensitive) but that exclude any other world which is not included in  the correctAnswer variable.

Is it possible to use RegExp in order to avoid any word that is NOT included in the pattern?

```
var correctAnswer:String = "Hello Dummy World";
var answer1:String = "hello world"; //should be a good answer
var answer2:String = "Hello dummy world"; //should be a good answer
var answer3:String = "Hello WRONG world";  //should be a wrong answer
var answer4:String = "Another String here";  //should be a wrong answer
function checkAnswer(a:String):String{
    var exp1:RegExp=/Hello|Dummy|World/ig;
    var r= a.replace(exp1,"OK");
    trace(a.search(exp1));
    return r
}
trace(checkAnswer(answer1)); // this should return "Hello Dummy World"
trace(checkAnswer(answer2)); // this should return "Hello Dummy World"
trace(checkAnswer(answer3)); // this should throw a wrong answer
trace(checkAnswer(answer4)); // this should throw a wrong answer
```

Now the output gives me:

```
0
OK OK // in place of "Hello Dummy World"
0
OK OK OK // in place of "Hello Dummy World"
0
OK WRONG OK // in place of "bad answer"
-1
Another String here // in place of "bad answer"
```

Sorry about my English and thank you if you could give me some advices / suggestions or a possible answer.

Maybe I should not use the RegExp Object in this case?
I'm not familiar with this, but If this may work, this is probably best than a conditional loop to test all the possible cases???

I'm a little confused here and hope that the question is clearly described.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will extract all the "words" inside the correct answer and removes *any occurrence* of them in the specified string, so that after the trimming nothing would be left but undesirables!

```
var correctAnswer:String = "Hello Dummy World";

var answer1:String = "hello world"; // Should be a good answer
var answer2:String = "Hello dummy world"; // Should be a good answer
var answer3:String = "Hello WRONG world";  // Should be a wrong answer
var answer4:String = "Another String here";  // Should be a wrong answer

var tokenized:Array = correctAnswer.split(" ");
function checkAnswer(a:String):Boolean{
    var exp:RegExp = new RegExp(tokenized.join("|"), "ig");
    var correctKeywordsRemoved:String = a.replace(exp, "");
    var isCorrect:Boolean = trim(correctKeywordsRemoved).length == 0;
    trace("Your answer of '"+a+"' is "+(isCorrect ? "CORRECT :)" : "WRONG :("));
    return isCorrect;

    function trim(s:String):String {
        return s.replace(/^\s*|\s*$/gim, "");
    }
}

checkAnswer(answer1); // Your answer of 'hello world' is CORRECT :)
checkAnswer(answer2); // Your answer of 'Hello dummy world' is CORRECT :)
checkAnswer(answer3); // Your answer of 'Hello WRONG world' is WRONG :(
checkAnswer(answer4); // Your answer of 'Another String here' is WRONG :(
```

Comment: This was exactly what I wanted.
I though that it was possible but I'm really a noob about Regular expressions!
Thank you for the time you spent @SomeOne !